# How can I reset Autocomplete value when it is selected?

Tags: jquery, input, autocomplete

```
<button type='reset' class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id='reset'>Reset</button>
```

I added a reset button inside my form to clear all the inputs but it doesn't work with autocomplete inputs.

[image: Auto complete field]

I also added custom jquery something like this.

```
$('#reset').click(function(){
$('#photographer').attr("value","");
$('.selectize-input').children('div.item').remove();
});
```

This jquery codes can clear the values but after I clear it and re-fill the value again it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you give more details ? or a https://jsfiddle.net/ link

Comment: Why don't you reset all the inputs manually ? something like this : `$(document).on("click", "#reset", function(){
    $("input").val("");
});`

Comment: Thanks for the help
It was my mistake. Actually, it's not about autocomplete. It's selectize js problem. I got the answer here http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/2gnq1ruv/204/ .